# What Ubuntu server administration books does the community recommend?

Tags: community, administration

What book would you recommend as a reference for Ubuntu server administration?

I'd like to not limit this to server-edition. I'm biased toward development environments that need to strike a balance somewhere between desktop & server.

*One book per answer, please - vote answers up/down as you feel appropriate. If you feel the book is biased towards/good for particular tasks, please mention them.*

Answer (score 10):

The [Ubuntu Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/index.html)([PDF](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/serverguide.pdf)) is free and written by the Ubuntu developers.

Answer (score 6):

I recommend the [Official Ubuntu Server Book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0137081332).

Comment: Why is the url behind the hyperlink a completely different one than the displayed name of the link suggests?

Comment: It would appear that SO modifies Amazon links to use their own affiliate code, instead of the one in the original link.

Comment: @andol @jdl - they do - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/26964/auto-inserting-stack-overflow-affiliate-into-all-amazon-book-links

Answer (score 3):

If you work with your Ubuntu Local team you can get a free copy of the Ubuntu Server book as Jono mentioned and is posted on the Fridge here: http://fridge.ubuntu.com/node/2094.

Also I enjoyed this one: Beginning Ubuntu LTS Server Administration: From Novice to Professional even though it is a bit older